# Web-to-lead API CORS issue

Tags: javascript, cors

I am using the We-to-lead form to populate Sales Force, but I would like the form to submit via AJAX rather than default form submission. The default form submission works fine and populates Sales Force, but I would prefer to not have the page redirect and for the form to use the same submission process as other contact forms on the site so that the success message format is the same etc.

When trying to use Axios to POST I get the following error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I have added localhost to the CORS whitelist in Sale Force, but this didn't work.

Here is my Axios POST request:

`axios.post( 'https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8', { data: data, headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' } }) .then( res => { this.setState({ sent: true }, this.resetForm()); console.log('Message sent!'); }) .catch( () => { console.log('Message not sent') });`

Is there away around this or do I *just* have to use the plain old submit?

Thanks,

Comment: `servlet.WebToLead` was [deprecated](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313062&type=1&mode=1) in 2018 and it certainly won't allow a CORS request.

Comment: 'https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8' is what I was given by the form generator for an account setup this week.. if thats deprecated, what should be used instead?

Comment: It depends on your integration approach and architecture. If plain submit works with your current code, stick with that for now. The out of the box SF option generates a web to lead form that posts to `servlet.WebToLead` (despite it being deprecated..). See [Integration Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_intro_overview.htm) for an overview of more sophisticated options.